# Shiny app with reactive data from survey package object

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, survey

I'm trying to build a simple app to look at responses to a Department of Education survey. I'm using the [survey package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) to adjust the raw data for the complex sampling design. This package has several built in functions, one of which is `svytable()`. The output of `svytable()` can be plotted directly with the base function `barplot()`. This is easy enough to do - but, I can't get it to work in a reactive data environment in Shiny.

(I'd love to be able to plot the data in this table with `ggplot2`, which is possible if you coerce the survey table object to a data frame but I thought I'd start one step at a time to see where I'm going wrong with the app.)

*Please let me know if you can identify what I'm getting wrong here:*

I've uploaded a sample of the data to this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11tooa1q_n34JMh_-vF7-v5PH1bQUT4SJ). Here is a simplified sample of my app code that is currently not working:

```
library(shiny)
library(foreign)
library(survey)

# Read in data (from wherever you save the data...)
secon_dat <- read.spss("FRSS_Short_Data.sav", 
                   use.value.labels = TRUE,
                   to.data.frame = TRUE)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Secondary Arts Teacher Data 2009-2010"),

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xVar",
                 "Select Questionnaire Item",
                choices = c("School enrollment size" = "SIZE", "School 
                            community type" = "URBAN", 
                            "School region" = "OEREG", "School minority enrollment" = "MINST", 
                            "Percent of students in the school eligible for free or reduced-price lunch" = "POVST", 
                            "School level" = "LEVEL"),
                selected = "School community type"),
    selectInput("groupVar",
                "Select Grouping Item",
                choices = c("School enrollment size" = "SIZE", "School community type" = "URBAN", 
                            "School region" = "OEREG", "School minority enrollment" = "MINST", 
                            "Percent of students in the school eligible for free or reduced-price lunch" = "POVST", 
                            "School level" = "LEVEL"),
                selected = "School region")
  ),
  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("Plot")

  )))

server <- function(input, output) {

dat <- reactive({

 # Define complex survey design with replicate weights
      jrr_dat <- svrepdesign(variables = secon_dat[, c(which(colnames(secon_dat) == input$xVar),
                                                  which(colnames(secon_dat) == input$groupVar))],
                        repweights = secon_dat[, 9:58],
                        data = secon_dat,
                        type = "JK1",
                        combined.weights = TRUE,
                        weights = secon_dat[, 8],
                        scale = 1, rscales = 1)

 plot_tab <- svytable(~input$xVar + input$groupVar, jrr_dat)

 res <- list(plot_tab = plot_tab)

})

output$Plot <- renderPlot({

 res <- dat()

 barplot(res$plot_tab)

 })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `secon_dat` has 58 columns but you wrote `secon_dat[, 253:302]`. Please, check.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I edited the code - it was an artifact of reducing the dataset to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the model formula for `svytable` as follows:

```
model.formula <- formula(paste0("~",input$xVar," + ",input$groupVar))
plot_tab <- svytable(model.formula, jrr_dat)
```

[image]

Comment: This is working! Thank you - could you tell me why my approach did not work? I'm thinking it was something to do with me not understanding the structure of the survey design object very well.

Comment: @PeterMiksza Your code in 99% correct. What do you need is to create the formula for `svytable` from the string variables `input$xVar` and `input$groupVar`. You cannot pass these strings directly into `svytable`

Comment: Thanks again, is there a way to get the svytable object to print as a contingency table in Shiny? I've tried something like this in the server - with an accompanying call to tableOutput() in the UI, but it only prints as a dataframe: output$rawData <- renderTable({ res <- dat() res$plot_tab })